# How to find negation of a set when sample space is not given?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem but I am stuck with how to find the negation of set B.

> If $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{1,4,9\}$, which one of the following is $A\cap\overline{B}$?
>
> - $\{1,2,3,4,5,9\}$
> - $\{1,4\}$
> - $\{2,3,5\}$
> - $\{9\}$

Is there any way to solve this problem. In found this problem on one of my text books.

Comment: You don't need the universe in this example, just the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$. If you just had $B^c$, then you need to have some universe.

Comment: could you please provide the solution as an example?

Comment: You need to do it. Go through the list for $A$ and discard those that are in $B$.